# Is there any advantage to using Buffered Streams when dealing with files if you're reading large chunks of data at a time?

Tags: java

If I'm dealing with files, usually i'll wrap the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` in `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` - to minimize the amount of file IO operations as possible to improve performance.

I believe this is considered good practice and is generally recommended.

The standard 'stream copy' code everyone uses when copying an `InputStream` to a `OutputStream` is this:

*(assuming they're not using a third party library and want to remain compatible with Java 6)*

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
for (int n = 0; (n = input.read(buffer)) != EOF; ) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
```

---

What got me thinking is, I could just set `BUFFER_SIZE` to 8192 (the default size of the buffers in `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`).

My question is, would it still be benefical to use `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`? I'm not entirely sure how these classes work under the hood, and I don't know if there would be any advantage to using them in this situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no, but if you're using a buffer whose size isn't a power of two there might be a benefit in having the reads and writes power-of-2-aligned by the `BufferedInputStream` or `BufferedOutputStream`, whose default buffer size is 8192 bytes. Buffers should ideally be a multiple of the file system block size, or better still the cluster size.

You should note that both these streams have greased paths when the transfer is larger than the internal buffer: the internal buffer is emptied and then the remainder of the transfer is direct, rather than going through the internal buffer and being copied twice. So, there is also no real *disadvantage.*

Answer (score 0):

No, if you need a `byte[]` from your input to give to your output, there would be no benefit. That is exactly what `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` do. Find an appropriate buffer size and use it.